# Java Generics: passing multiple types to diamond

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, android-livedata

In android there is a class called `MediatorLiveData<T>` which acts as a ... mediator for LiveData.

There are situations like when we need to validate multiple live data objects and get a boolean value from them; we make a `CombinedLiveData<T,U,S>` and extend `MediatorLiveData<S>` so we can pass a higer-order function which accepts `t:T, u:U` and returns an `S`.

Imagine when we have to pass unlimited amount of `T`s to this class and return a value of `S`: We have to make a `CLD_12<T1,T2,...T12,S>` and another one for 13 inputs, very frustrating.

So I am asking if there is a way to say `CLD<T1..., S> : MLD<S>()` or another way make this happen.

#### edit: adding the code

```
class CombinedLiveData2<T, K, S>(
source1: LiveData<T>,
source2: LiveData<K>,
private val combine: (data1: T?, data2: K?) -> S
) : MediatorLiveData<S>() {

private var data1: T? = null
private var data2: K? = null

init {
    super.addSource(source1) {
        data1 = it
        value = combine(data1, data2)
    }
    super.addSource(source2) {
        data2 = it
        value = combine(data1, data2)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So `T1`, `T2`, ..., `T12` all have to be different types?

Comment: It think it's not possible. Could you add your CombinedLiveData code, then it would be easier to understand how you what to use this T1 combined type.

Comment: @Sanlok-Lee usually yes, but if there could be a solution even for same `T`s I would make a use of it.